# Display all values in PSCustomObject array

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, foreach

I realise this may be a basic question, but I couldn't find anything on google or on here. If this question has already been asked, I apologise.

Here is my code:

```
$process1 = (Get-Process).Name
$process2 = (Get-Process).Name

$objects = [pscustomobject]@{
  process1 = $process1
  process2 = $process2
}

foreach ($object in $objects) {
  $object | Format-Table process1, process2
}
```

I would like to display a two column table (`process1` and `process2`), with each row being a value from the corresponding array. Much like how it would look if I just wrote `$object.value1` but with two columns, like this:

```
Process1                     Process2
---------                    ---------
ace_engine                   ace_engine
ace_update                   ace_update
ApplicationFrameHost         ApplicationFrameHost
```

Instead of my current output:

```
process1                                                      process2
--------                                                      --------
{ace_engine, ace_engine, ace_update, ApplicationFrameHost...} {ace_engine, ace_engine, ace_update, ApplicationFrameHost...}
```

Comment: Why not just `$objects |Format-Table *`? The objects only has the two properties anyway

Comment: Could you show an example of what you would like your output to look like?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  Your first two lines assign an array of values to two variables, and then you never use those variables again.  Your custom object, on the other hand, uses two variables that are wholly undefined.

Comment: Just included an example and amended the issue you noted @BaconBits, hope it is clearer now?

Comment: @user209030, you can expand out arrays like this: (@($process1) -join ',')